# Can Raygun be set up to report all uncaught exceptions in an Azure worker role?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-worker-roles, raygun, raygun.io

Can Raygun be used to report uncaught exceptions in an Azure worker role? Or do caught exceptions have to be sent to Raygun manually? I have added the following lines to my app.config

```
<configSections>
    <section name="RaygunSettings" type="Mindscape.Raygun4Net.RaygunSettings, Mindscape.Raygun4Net" />
</configSections>
<RaygunSettings apikey="my_key" />
```

I have also added the following to WorkerRole.cs:

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint, IRaygunApplication
{
    private static readonly RaygunClient _raygunClient = new RaygunClient();

    public RaygunClient GenerateRaygunClient()
    {
        return _raygunClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the type of issue you have. Are events not coming to the backend? https://github.com/MindscapeHQ/raygun4net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to follow the instructions [here](https://raygun.com/blog/2014/02/windows-service-exception-handling/?utm_content=buffer41535&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer).

The complete set up for a worker role is:

Add your api key to the service configuration

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
    <Setting name="Raygun.ApiKey" value="my_key" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

Install the RayGun4Net Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mindscape.Raygun4Net/

Add a section to your app.config

```
configSections>
    <section name="RaygunSettings" type="Mindscape.Raygun4Net.RaygunSettings, Mindscape.Raygun4Net" />
</configSections>
```

Update WorkerRole.cs

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        return base.OnStart();
    }

void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var raygunClient = new RaygunClient(ConfigHelpers.GetAppSetting("Raygun.ApiKey"));

        raygunClient.Send((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
    }
```